# when the variable is set before array is used, it is not working.

Tags: unix

i am new to unix. i am trying to dump out a few files based on the array that is set.

for example:

```
set my_n = Apple
arrayme="fruit name misc"

for x in $arrayme; do
echo "I am $my_n" > $my_n_$x.txt
done
```

where i would like the output files to be :
      Apple_fruit.txt, Apple_name.txt, Apple_misc.txt

i want to set this $my_n so that i can reuse for other $my_n variable that could be set upon it. but i not able to get it working. need help to take alook on the syntax above.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On line 1, the use of set in not needed. Do not add spaces between the variable name & and equals, and equals & value.

On line 5 you must enclose the variable ***my_n*** in curly braces to distinguish it from the underscore separator you use.

```
1    my_n=Apple
2    arrayme="fruit name misc"
3
4    for x in $arrayme; do
5    echo "I am $my_n" > ${my_n}_$x.txt
6    done
```

This updated code should work as expected.